# How to grep/sed/awk for a range of output starting with a whitespace character

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
# cat $file
...
ip access-list extended DOG-IN
 permit icmp 10.10.10.1 0.0.0.7 any
 permit tcp 10.11.10.1 0.0.0.7 eq www 443 10.12.10.0 0.0.0.63
 deny   ip any any log
ip access-list extended CAT-IN
 permit icmp 10.13.10.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.14.10.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.10.10
 permit tcp 10.16.10.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.17.10.10 eq smtp
...
```

I want to be able to search by name (using a script) to get 'section' output for independent access-lists. I want the output to look like this:

```
# grep -i dog $file | sed <options??>

ip access-list extended DOG-IN
 permit icmp 10.10.10.1 0.0.0.7 any
 permit tcp 10.11.10.1 0.0.0.7 eq www 443 10.12.10.0 0.0.0.63
 deny   ip any any log
```

...with no further output of inapplicable non-indented lines.

I have tried the following:

```
grep -A 10 DOG $file | sed -n '/^[[:space:]]\{1\}/p'
```

...Which only gives me the 10 lines after DOG which begin with a single space (including lines not applicable to the searched access-list).

```
sed -n '/DOG/,/^[[:space:]]\{1\}/p' $file
```

...Which gives me the line containing DOG, and the next line beginning with a single space. (Need *all* the applicable lines of the access-list...)

I want the line containing DOG, and all lines after DOG which begin with a single space, until the next un-indented line. There are too many variables in the content to depend on any patterns other than the leading space (there is not always a deny on the end, etc...).

Answer (score 5):

Using ***GNU* `sed` (Linux)**:

```
name='dog'  # case-INsensitive name of section to extract
sed -n "/$name/I,/^[^[:space:]]/ { /$name/I {p;d}; /^[^[:space:]]/q; p }" file
```

<sup>To make matching case-*sensitive*, remove the `I` after the occurrences of `/I` above.</sup>

- `-n` suppresses default output so that output must explicitly be requested inside the script with functions such as `p`.
- Note the use of *double* quotes (`"..."`) around the `sed` script, so as to allow references to the *shell* variable `$name`: The double quotes ensure that the shell variable references are expanded BEFORE the script is handed to `sed` (`sed` itself has no access to shell variables).

  - *Caveat*: This technique is tricky, because (a) you must use shell escaping to escape *shell* metacharacters you want to pass through to `sed`, such as `$` as `\$`, and (b) the shell-variable value must not contain *`sed`* metacharacters that could break the `sed` script; for generic escaping of shell-variable values for use in `sed` scripts, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29613573#29613573) of mine, or use my [`awk`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254879/45375).
- `/$name/I,/^[^[:space:]]/` uses a *range* to match the line of interest (`/$name/I`; the trailing `I` is GNU `sed`'s case-insensitivity matching option) through the start of the *next* section (`/^[^[:space:]]/` - i.e., the next line that does NOT start with whitespace); since `sed` ranges are always *inclusive*, the challenge is to selectively remove the last line of the range, IF it is the start of the *next* section - note that this will NOT be the case if the section of interest is the LAST one in the file.
  Note that the commands inside `{ ... }` are only executed for each line in the range.
- `/$name/I {p;d};` unconditionally prints the 1st line of the range: `d` deletes the line (which has already been printed) and starts the next cycle (proceeds to the next input line).
- `/^[^[:space:]]/q` matches the last line in the range, IF it is the *next* section's first line, and quits processing altogether (`q`), without printing the line.
- `p` is then only reached for section-interior lines and prints them.

Note:

- The assumption is that header lines can be identified by NOT starting with a whitespace char., and that any other lines are non-header lines - if more sophisticated matching is required, see [my `awk`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254879/45375).
- This solution has the slight disadvantage that the range regexes must be duplicated, although you could mitigate that with shell variables.

---

**FreeBSD/macOS `sed`** can *almost* do the same, except that it **lacks the case-insensitivity option, `I`**.

```
name='DOG'  # case-SENSITIVE name of section to extract
sed -n -e "/$name/,/^[^[:space:]]/ { /$name/ {p;d;}; /^[^[:space:]]/q; p; }" file
```

Note that FreeBSD/OSX `sed` generally has stricter syntax requirements, such as the `;` after a command even when followed by `}`.

If you do need case-insensitivity, see [my `awk`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254879/45375).

Comment: +1, thank - awesome explaination - helped me to modify it to my needs (do not print the header + do not quit after the first match but continue with other matches): 

    sed -n "/$name/I,/^[^[:space:]]/ { /$name/I d; /^[^[:space:]]/ d; p }" file

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -vfound=0 '
/DOG/{
    found = !found;
    print;
    next
}

/^[[:space:]]/{
    if (found) {
        print;
        next
    }
}

{ found = !found }
'
```

You can substitute any ERE in place of `/DOG/`, such as `/(DOG)|(CAT)/`, and the rest of the script will do the work. You can condense it if you like of course.

Note that just because a line begins with a space, that doesn't mean there is only one space. `/^[[:space:]]{1}/` will match the leading space, even in a string like

```
                      nonspace
```

meaning it is equivalent to `/^[[:space:]]/`. If your format is so rigid that there must always only be a single space, use `/^[[:space:]][^[:space:]]/` instead. Lines like the one with "nonspace" above will not be matched.

Answer (score 2):

@mklement0 squeezed my already-inscrutable sed down to this:

```
sed '/^ip/!{H;$!d};x; /DOG/I!d'
```

which swaps accumulated multiline groups into the pattern buffer for processing -- the main logic (`/DOG/I!d` here) operates on whole groups.

The `/^ip/!` identifies continuation lines by the absence of a first-line marker and accumulates them, so the `x` only runs when an entire group has been accumulated.

Some corner cases don't apply here:

The first `x` swaps in a phantom empty group at the start.  If that doesn't get dropped during ordinary processing, adding a `1d` fixes that.

The last `x` also swaps *out* the last line of the file.  That's usually just  last line of the last group, already accumulated by the `H`,  but if some command might produce one-line groups you need to supply a fake one at the end (with e.g. `echo "header phantom" | sed '/^header/!{H;$!d};x' realdata.txt -`, or `{ showgroups; echo header phantom; } | sed '/^header/!{H;$!d};x'`.

Comment: Also, couldn't this be simplified to `sed '/firstline/! {H;$!d;}; x` and thus, in the case at hand, `sed '/^ip/! {H;$!d;}; x; /DOG/!d' file`? I'm unclear on what `1d` does in your solution; removing it seems to make no difference. Note that if the last line is a _header_ line, it is ignored by both solutions.

Comment: `x` swaps in the previously-accumulated group, and on the first line there isn't one.  You're right that it makes no difference here. And you're right that this doesn't work well with mixed multi-line and single-line groups, but for command-output postprocessors like this that's pretty much never a problem.

Comment: +1 for the shortest solution and a handy `sed` idiom in general, though it's certainly not easy to understand. Note that for case-INsensitive matching you need _GNU_ `sed` and its `I` matching option: `/dog/I!d`. Obviously, this solution relies on all header lines starting with string `ip` - a fair assumption, given the sample input data.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the `1d` - makes sense to have it there in general. With that in mind: is `sed '/firstline/! {H;$!d;}; x; 1d'` equivalent to your solution (and thus slightly simpler), or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you!  I rebuilt the answer to incorporate that improvement and address your questions directly, much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

I added a second answer as mklement0 pointed a flaw on my logic.

This is yet a very simple way to do that in Perl:

`perl -ne ' /^\w+/ && {$p=0}; /DOG/ && {$p=1}; $p && {print}'`

EXAMPLES:

```
cat /tmp/file  | perl -ne ' /^\w+/ && {$p=0}; /DOG/ && {$p=1}; $p && {print}'
ip access-list extended DOG-IN
 permit icmp 10.10.10.1 0.0.0.7 any
 permit tcp 10.11.10.1 0.0.0.7 eq www 443 10.12.10.0 0.0.0.63
 deny   ip any any log

cat /tmp/file  | perl -ne ' /^\w+/ && {$p=0}; /CAT/ && {$p=1}; $p && {print}'
ip access-list extended CAT-IN
 permit icmp 10.13.10.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.14.10.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.10.10
 permit tcp 10.16.10.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.17.10.10 eq smtp
```

EXPLANATION:

If the line starts with [a-z0-9_] set $p false

If the line contains PATTERN in this case DOG sets $p true

if $p true prints

Comment: +1; nicely done; in `awk` it would even be shorter: `awk '/^[[:alnum:]_]/ {p=0}  /DOG/ {p=1}  p'`. (In POSIX `awk`, you can't do `\w`, but you could in GNU `awk`.). Quibble: you don't strictly need the `+`.

Comment: Thanks for the awk alternative, I love idiomatic awk!

Answer (score 1):

A shorter, **POSIX-compliant `awk` solution**, which is a generalized and optimized translation of [@Tiago's excellent Perl-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266514/45375).

<sup>One advantage of these answers over the `sed` solutions is that they use *literal substring* matching rather than regular expressions, which allows passing in arbitrary search strings, without needing to worry about escaping.   That said, if you *did* want regex matching, use the `~` operator rather than the `index()` function; e.g., `index($0, name)` would become `$0 ~ name`. You then have to make sure that the value passed for `name` either contains no accidental regex metacharacters meant to be treated as literals *or* is an intentionally crafted regex.</sup>

```
name='DOG' # Case-sensitive name to search for.

awk -v name="$name" '/^[^[:space:]]/ {if (p) exit; if (index($0,name)) {p=1}}  p' file
```

- *Option* `-v name="$name"` defines *`awk`* variable `name` based on the value of *shell* variable `$name` (`awk` has no direct access to shell variables).
- *Variable* `p` is used as a flag to indicate whether the current line should be printed, i.e., whether it is part of the section of interest; as long as `p` is not initialized, it is treated as `0` (false) in a Boolean context.
- *Pattern* `/^[^[:space:]]/` matches only header lines (lines that start with a non-whitespace character), and  the associated *action* (`{...}`) is only processed for them:

  - `if (p) exit` exits processing altogether, if `p` is already set, because that implies that the *next* section has been reached. Exiting right away has the benefit of not having to process the remainder of the file.
  - `if (index($0, name))` looks for the name of interest as a *literal substring* in the header line at hand, and, if found (in which case `index() returns the 1-based position at which the substring was found, which is interpreted as`true`in a Boolean context), sets flag`p`to`1`(`{p=1}`).
- `p` simply prints the current line, if `p` is `1`, and does nothing otherwise. That is, once the section header of interest has been found, it and subsequent lines are printed (up until the next section or the end of the input file).
  Note that this is an example of a pattern-only command: *only a pattern* (condition) is specified, without an associated action (`{...}`), in which case the default action is to print the current line, if the pattern evaluates to true. (That technique is used in the common shorthand `1` to simply *unconditionally* print the current record.)

If **case-INsensitivity** is needed:

```
name='dog' # Case-INsensitive name to search for.

awk -v name="$name" \
  '/^[^[:space:]]/ {if(p) exit; if(index(tolower($0),tolower(name))) {p=1}}  p' file
```

<sup>*Caveat*: The BSD-based `awk` that comes with macOS (still applies as of 10.12.1) is not *UTF-8-aware.*: the case-insensitive matching won't work with non-ASCII letters such as `ü`.</sup>

*GNU* `awk` alternative, using the special `IGNORECASE` variable:

```
awk -v name="$name" -v IGNORECASE=1 \
  '/^[^[:space:]]/ {if(p) exit; if(index($0,name)) {p=1}}  p' file
```

---

Another POSIX-compliant `awk` solution:

```
name='dog' # Case-insensitive name of section to extract.

awk -v name="$name" '
 index(tolower($0),tolower(name)) {inBlock=1; print; next} # 1st section line found.
 inBlock && !/^[[:space:]]/       {exit}             # Exit at start of next section.
 inBlock                                             # Print 2nd, 3rd, ... section line.
 ' file
```

Note:

- `next` skips the remaining pattern-action pairs and proceeds to the next line.
- `/^[[:space:]]/` matches lines that start with *at least one* whitespace char. As @Chrono Kitsune explains in his answer, if you wanted to match lines that start with *exactly one* whitespace char., use `/^[[:space:]][^[:space:]]/`. Also note that, despite its name, character class `[:space:]` matches ANY form of whitespace, not just spaces - see `man isspace`.
- There's no need to initialize flag variable `inBlock`, as it defaults to `0` in numeric/Boolean contexts.
- If you have *GNU* `awk`, you can more easily achieve case-insensitive matching by setting the `IGNORECASE` variable to a nonzero value (`-v IGNORECASE=1`) and simply using `index($0, name)` inside the program.

---

A *GNU* `awk` solution, IF, you can assume that all section header lines start with `'ip'` (so as to break the input into sections that way, rather than looking for leading whitespace):

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)ip' -F'\n' -v name="$name" -v IGNORECASE=1 '
  index($1, name) { sub(/\n$/, ""); print "ip" $0; exit }
  ' file
```

- `-v RS='(^|\n)ip'` breaks the input into records by lines that fall between line-starting instances of string `'ip'`.
- `-F'\n'` then breaks each record into fields (`$1`, ...) by lines.
- `index($1, name)` looks for the name on the current record's *first* line - case-INsensitively, thanks to `-v IGNORECASE=1`.
- `sub(/\n$/, "")` removes any trailing `\n`, which can stem from the section of interest being the *last* in the input file.
- `print "ip" $0` prints the matching record, comprising the entire section of interest - since, however the record doesn't include the *separator*, `'ip'`, it is prepended.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is: `sed '/DOG/, /^ip/ !d' | sed '$d'`

```
cat file | sed '/DOG/, /^ip/ !d' | sed '$d'
ip access-list extended DOG-IN
 permit icmp 10.10.10.1 0.0.0.7 any
 permit tcp 10.11.10.1 0.0.0.7 eq www 443 10.12.10.0 0.0.0.63
 deny   ip any any log
```

Explanation:

- first sed command prints from the line containing `DOG` to the next line starting with `ip`
- second sed command deletes the last line(which is the line starting with `ip`)

Comment: The issue with blindly deleting the last line is that it won't work as intended if the block of interest is the _last_ one in the file: Since that last block won't be terminated with a line from the _next_ block (because there is none by definition), you'll end up deleting a line that you shouldn't.